# intercept TCP traffic on compromised router

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, router

I have this configuration

```
GATEWAY1 <----> ROUTER <---> GATEWAY2
```

I am on the compromised router, and I want to intercept/block the packets that come from G1,edit them , and forward on Gateway 2,acting as a `MiTM`.
I know that I can edit packets with `Scapy`, but how I can stop them to reach the original destination?

Gateway 1 and 2 are on `Debian "squeeze"`.
The Router has `Kali`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop the packages you don't want to forward.

Routing is an active task, and the router has to decide what to do with each packet. Scapy itself doesn't allow dropping, because it's simply a passive sniffer. You can either use the python-iptables package to drop the packets, or use a different MitM solution altogether.